# HybridAuth Google+ sign-in error: redirect_uri_mismatch

Tags: php, google-plus, hybridauth

Trying to implement hybridauth 2.4 on my website,
All codes except config.php are out of the box, but I am having problems with Google+. I have tried everything and am slowly loosing it.

```
400 Error: redirect_uri_mismatch
```

Example Url: http://runettv.com/examples/social_hub/

My redirect uri's set in google console:

```
http://runettv.com/hybridauth
http://runettv.com/hybridauth/
http://runettv.com/hybridauth/examples
http://runettv.com/hybridauth/examples/
```

I also tried `localhost:8080, localhost:8080/` etc.

My `base_url` is `http://runettv.com/hybridauth`

Not sure how to troubleshoot.
Has anyone succeeded with this?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

The configured redirect_uri and used redirect_uri have to match exactly. Add `http://runettv.com/hybridauth?hauth.done=Google` to your app configuration and you should be good.

Comment: @PavelLebedeff to help others you should accept this answer.

Comment: This answer is still valid. So that others can be helped as you have, you should simply accept it.